# Integral that depends on itself

Tags: integration

I have a vertical string hanging under its own weight so $v(t)=\sqrt{T/ \rho}=\sqrt{(l-s(t))g}$. If I want to find the distance traveled by a pulse in a time $t$ is get $s(t)=\int_0^t \sqrt{(l-s(t))g} dt'$.

How can I solve an integral of this form?

Comment: I don't know what depends on $t$ in your integral but it seems to me it is equivalent to some ODE because $s(t) =\int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{(l-s)g}\text{d}t'$ gives $s'(t)=\sqrt{(l-s(t))g}$ with $s(0)=0$.

Comment: Ah okay, you're right it just a separable first order ODE! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy if it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your clarifications, we have the following (note that $s(0)=0$):

$$\begin{align}
s(t) &= \int_{0}^{t}\sqrt{(l-s(t))g}\text{d}t'\\
s'(t) &= \sqrt{(l-s(t))g}\\
\frac{s'(t)}{\sqrt{l-s(t)}} &=\sqrt{g}\\
\frac{\text{d}s}{\sqrt{l-s}} &=\sqrt{g}\text{d}t\\
\int \frac{\text{d}s}{\sqrt{l-s}} &= \int\sqrt{g}\text{d}t\\
\end{align}$$
which gives
$$-2\sqrt{l-s(t)}=t\sqrt{g}+K$$
and as the initial condition is $s(0)=0$, we get $K=-2\sqrt{l}$. Because of the square root, this equation exists only if $t\le 2\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$. We have the following:
\begin{align}
-2\sqrt{l-s(t)} &= t\sqrt{g}-2\sqrt{l} \\
\sqrt{l-s(t)} &= \sqrt{l}-t\frac{\sqrt{g}}{2}\\
s(t) &= l-\left(\sqrt{l}-t\frac{\sqrt{g}}{2}\right)^{2}\\
s(t) &= -t^{2}\frac{g}{4}+t\sqrt{lg}
\end{align}
where $t\in\left[0\,,\,2\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}\right]$. The condition $s(t)\le l$ is always verified.